# Special Characters in WCF REST ATOM Feed

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF ATOM Feed Service using the WCF REST Toolkit with the following UriTemplate

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{category}/?numItems={numItems}")]
public Atom10FeedFormatter GetFeedByCategory(string category, int numItems)
```

Most cases work, the edge is when I try to load the feed based on the category with a # sign.  I am loading courses for category='C#' and all the service ever sees is 'C'.  Both of these links are doing that. Does anyone know if there is some special way to escape this character in for WCF?

- http://myservice.uri/Service.svc/C#/?numItems=5
- http://myservice.uri/Service.svc/C%23/?numItems=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on MSDN Forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d03c8331-1e98-4d5d-82a7-390942a93012/